# Query for customer quotes by date range

Tags: performance, sql, oracle

I have a table (Oracle):

```
customer_quote
------
int id
int part_key (fk)
int condition_code (fk)
number unit_price
int qty_quoted
date entry_date
```

With a query that selects data from the past year:

```
SELECT cq.part_key 
    , cq.condition_code 
    , COUNT(*) AS cq_count 
    , SUM(cq.unit_price * cq.qty_quoted) AS cq_total 
    , SUM(cq.qty_quoted) cq_qty
FROM customer_quote cq 
WHERE cq.entry_date > TO_DATE('09-Jun-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
GROUP BY cq.part_key 
    , cq.condition_code
```

But I needed the data to include parts with activity from the past two years but data older than 1 year shouldn't calculate into the totals. So I wrote this query:

```
SELECT cq.part_key 
    , cq.condition_code 
    , COUNT(case when cq.entry_date > TO_DATE('09-Jun-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy') then 1 END) AS cq_count 
    , SUM(case when cq.entry_date > TO_DATE('09-Jun-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy') then (cq.unit_price * cq.qty_quoted) END) AS cq_total 
    , SUM(case when cq.entry_date > TO_DATE('09-Jun-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy') then cq.qty_quoted END) cq_qty
FROM customer_quote cq 
WHERE cq.entry_date > TO_DATE('09-Jun-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
GROUP BY cq.part_key 
    , cq.condition_code
```

The `where` date is 2 years ago but the `case when` dates are all 1 year ago. This query works, but is it optimal? I think there's probably a way to merge the `case when` statements into 1.

Performance is my main concern, readability is only marginally important.

Worth noting: the final SQL query will be a parameterized SQL Java object so the date will be a `CASE WHEN cq.entry_date > ? THEN` and inserted using `PreparedStatement::setDate()` so with my solution I will need to do `setDate()` x 4.

Answer (score 2):

I think the query is optimal enough. The truth is query can retrieve a result only by accessing 2 years data, so given `WHERE` condition is must. And the query access rows only once. At performance aspect, table access method (through `index` or by `full scan`) is critical, but Oracle Optimizer will choose it by referring statistics information.

Answer (score 1):

To optimize this query, I would only perform the date checks once, regardless of how Oracle optimizes internally.

> ```
> , COUNT(case when cq.entry_date > TO_DATE('09-Jun-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy') then 1 END) AS cq_count 
>     , SUM(case when cq.entry_date > TO_DATE('09-Jun-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy') then (cq.unit_price * cq.qty_quoted) END) AS cq_total 
>     , SUM(case when cq.entry_date > TO_DATE('09-Jun-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy') then cq.qty_quoted END) cq_qty
> FROM customer_quote cq
> ```

could be rewritten as:
[Fiddle Oracle 11g Release2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e18566f4b9b224b92394ca57dfdf166d)

```
select part_key 
    ,  condition_code 
    ,  count(recent) cq_count 
    ,  sum(case when recent = 1 then (unit_price * qty_quoted) end) cq_total 
    ,  sum(case when recent = 1 then qty_quoted end) cq_qty
from (
    select q.* 
        , case when entry_date > add_months(trunc(sysdate),-12) then 1 end recent
        from customer_quote q
    where entry_date > add_months(trunc(sysdate),-24)
) lookup 
group by part_key, condition_code
--order by 1, 2
```